# Codeigniter Project On Ubuntu Nginx - Login not working

Tags: codeigniter, nginx

This is nginx configuration file
    # Default server configuration
    #
    server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

```
root /var/www/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name  192.168.0.40;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }


    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php5-cgi alone:
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php5-fpm:
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
```

}

However login is working fine on apache but not on nginx